# How to set date limit in JTCalender?

Tags: ios, swift, jtcalendar

I want to set date limit in `JTCalender`. As of now it shows dates more than of past year & more than a year ahead of current year. I want to set limit that it should show only dates of past 6 months & future 6 months. I am using swift language. Please suggest how to resolve this issue ?

EDIT: I am using below code in my app also.

```
func calendarDidLoadNextPage(_ calendar: JTCalendarManager!) {

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy"
    print("load next date \(calendar.date())")
    label_month.text = formatter.string(from: calendar.date()).uppercased()
    filterDate(cal_date: calendar.date())
  }

  func calendarDidLoadPreviousPage(_ calendar: JTCalendarManager!) {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy"
    print("loading previous date is \(self.dateFormatter().string(from: calendar.date()))")
    label_month.text = formatter.string(from: calendar.date()).uppercased()
    filterDate(cal_date: calendar.date())
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create **Max** and **Min** Date as per your requirement and use JTCalendar's delegate method to limit the date of calendar.

In your **Interface**

```
 NSDate *_todayDate;
 NSDate *_minDate;
 NSDate *_maxDate;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) JTCalendarManager *calendarManager;
```

In implementation section, you can do below code.

```
_calendarManager = [JTCalendarManager new];
_calendarManager.delegate = self;

_todayDate = [NSDate date];

_minDate = [_calendarManager.dateHelper addToDate:_todayDate months:-6];

_maxDate = [_calendarManager.dateHelper addToDate:_todayDate months:6];
```

**And A delegate method is there to limit the date for the calendar**

```
// Used to limit the date for the calendar, optional
- (BOOL)calendar:(JTCalendarManager *)calendar canDisplayPageWithDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    return [_calendarManager.dateHelper date:date isEqualOrAfter:_minDate andEqualOrBefore:_maxDate];
}
```

The problem is your condition in your delegate method.

```
func calendar(_ calendar: JTCalendarManager!, canDisplayPageWith date: Date!) -> Bool {

    return (calendarManager?.dateHelper.date(minDate, isEqualOrAfter: maxDate))!
  }
```

You are passing **minDate** to check **isEqualorAfter** to your **maxDate**. which will n ever be true.

Comment: scroll is freezed. I am not able to scroll left & right

Comment: how you have set date ? can you post the code so Can have look and post the code for swift as well

Comment: **canDisplayPageWithDate** you just need to set the Max and Min date in this delegate method.

Comment: @dhiraj i think you need to change the method you use regarding DateHelper.

Comment: use that method in which you can use **isEqualOrAfter** and **andEqualOrBefore** both. your code must be returning false due to your delegate method condition.